# Game Maker creating pop up message

Tags: gml

i tried to make a pop up message in game maker 8.1 and it has no design. I tried to find some tutorials but it not works. what will i do to create a pop up message with design?

Answer (score 2):

There is documentation on the http://docs.yoyogames.com (specifically under the GML overview) that may be able to help.

You can use theses functions to change the way a pop up looks.

```
message_text_font();    //Sets the font for the text in the pop-up box.
message_button_font();  //Sets the font for the buttons in the pop-up box.
message_input_font();   //Sets the font for the input field in the pop-up box.
```